# Trigger inserting deleted rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I've got two tables, `a` and `b`, both have two rows `int` and `date`. I want to write a trigger that, when deleting rows from table `a`, copies them to table `b` with the date changed to the current date. So, if I delete a row with `13, 2015-01-01` today from table `a`, `13, 2015-06-08` gets inserted into table `b`.
Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: What have you tried? What you describe doesn't sound difficult, so I am unclear on what exactly is giving you trouble.

Comment: I have a problem with the function. I don't know if deleted rows are stored somewhere, that I can copy them from. I've thought of making a temporary table in which I would change the date, but that's it.

Comment: Post the code of your function.

Comment: For a general solution of an audit trigger, see the Postgres Wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create or replace function a_adr_tf() returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into b(aid, awhen) values (old.id, now());
  return old;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger a_adr after delete from a for each row execute procedure a_adr_tf();
```

Note that this trigger does not take care of possible duplicate primary key in the table `b`. I have assumed the columns in `A` are called `id` and `when` and in `B` they are called `aid` and `awhen`.

You can solve the problem of the primary key of `B` by having a PK in `B` of the type serial, or, if you want just one row in `B` with the same `id` from `A` with a trigger deleting from `B` when a new row is inserted into `A`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only thing I didn't know was the `old.id` part.